# Error in initialization of a pointer to structure

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have this program that I'm trying to modify it, but I don't understand why the statement:
struct Link * temp = cap;
doesn't print me the number that I assigned to the linked list.
Thanks in advance!

```
struct Link
{
    int data;
    struct Link *urmatorul;
};

void Insert(Link * cap, int n)
{
    struct Link * temp = (Link*)malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    temp->data = n;
    temp->urmatorul = NULL;
    if(cap != NULL)
        temp->urmatorul = cap;
    cap = temp;
}

void Print(Link * cap)
{
    struct Link *temp = cap;
    printf(" %d", cap->data);
    printf("The number is: ");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->urmatorul;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct Link * cap;
    cap = NULL;
    printf("How many numbers? \n");
    int x, n, i;
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    for(i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        Insert(cap, n);
        Print(cap);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C passes arguments by value. Your `cap` is `NULL`, never changed after `Insert()`.

Comment: Think back to your text-books or class-notes. What do they say about passing arguments to functions? Do you remember anything about it be *by value*? Which means they are copied, and no matter how much you modify the copy inside the function, the original will never change? Do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Insert needs to return the new root node of your linked list.  Your insert function is leaking memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `Link *` by reference to change it, that's a `Link **`

```
void Insert(Link **cap, int n)
{
    struct Link * temp = (Link*)malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    temp->data = n;
    temp->urmatorul = NULL;
    if(*cap != NULL)
        temp->urmatorul = *cap;
    *cap = temp;
}
```

and in your `main(...)` use

```
Insert(&cap, n);
```

or you could return the new `Link *` from your `Insert(...)` like this;

```
Link * Insert(Link * cap, int n)
{
    struct Link * temp = (Link*)malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    temp->data = n;
    temp->urmatorul = NULL;
    if(cap != NULL)
        temp->urmatorul = cap;
    return temp;
}
```

and in your `main(...)` use

```
cap = Insert(cap, n);
```

Comment: `return cap = temp;` is a meaningless assignment. Of course, even a weak optimizer will remove it, but it's semantically incorrect.  Just return temp.

Answer (score 1):

This line does not do anything, because `cap` inside `Insert` is a copy of `cap` from the `main`:

```
cap = temp;
```

The change gets discarded as soon as `Insert` exits, so `main`'s `cap` remains `NULL`.

Change `Insert`'s signature to return `Link*`, and assign it to `cap` in the call from `main`:

```
Link* Insert(Link * cap, int n)
{
    struct Link * temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Link)); // No need to cast
    temp->data = n;
    temp->urmatorul = cap; // No need for the conditional
    return temp;
}
```

The call looks like this:

```
cap = Insert(cap, n);
```